# Looking for a comprehensive reference for vector identities

Tags: reference-request, vectors

Is there a reference containing a comprehensive list of vector identities, beyond the "usual" ones? Let's say that a vector identity is "usual," or "standard," if it can be found in the Wikipedia articles "Vector algebra relations" or "Vector calculus identities." I'm interested in (lesser-known) identities both with and without the nabla operator.

Surprisingly, for example, [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://books.google.com/books?id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&lpg=PP1&dq=Gradshteyn%20and%20Ryzhik&pg=PA1049#v=onepage&q=10%20Vector%20Field%20Theory&f=false) list only very standard identities.

The motivation for this request is that I have stumbled upon (and proven) an obscure-looking identity, some sort of a scalar-valued cousin of this one: $\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\left(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C}\right)\right)\mathbf{D}=\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)\left(\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{C}\right)+\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)\left(\mathbf{C}\times\mathbf{A}\right)+\left(\mathbf{C}\cdot\mathbf{D}\right)\left(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}\right)$. This latter one, unlike the one I have stumbled on, *is* listed on both of the above-mentioned Wikipedia articles. Since such "discoveries" are bound to happen from time to time, it would be nice to have a comprehensive reference...

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove such vector identities, all you need is the following. Let $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ ($i,j,k=1,2,3$) denote the Kronecker delta and the Levi-Civita tensor. The cross-product of two vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ can be written as $(\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B})_i = \sum_{j,k}\epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k$.These are the **only** isotropic tensors i.e., invariant under rotations. Any invariant tensor that you can construct can be written using these two tensors.

With this background, there is only ONE identity worth remembering.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} = \left(\delta_{jl} \delta_{km} - \delta_{jm} \delta{kl}\right)
$$
That is the reason books rarely go beyond giving some identities that appear often. Try to prove the equality of the identity that you mention using this method.

Comment: My question was *not* about how to prove it. 

As I wrote in the question statement, I have already proven it. Vector identity proofs are indeed usually straightforward *once you know what to prove*. On the other hand, it is not so easy to *come up* with identities, esp. if they involve four or more vectors.

Furthermore, having a reference listing a whole bunch of identities is very useful---after all, these identities are used for proving other stuff; to figure out which identity will be useful in any given derivation, it is very helpful to have an overview of what identities are available.